# php filesize не может определить размер картинки

Tags: php

добрый день. залили сайт на хостинг и проводим финальное тестирование. столкнулись с проблемой. есть функция для нарезания картинок.там используется

```
$fileSize = filesize($img_full_path);
```

проблема возникает при загрузке больших картинок( свыше 5000х5000 пикселей), выдает

```
Warning: filesize(): stat failed for (путь к картинке)
```

может кто стыкался с подобным и сможет задать направление куда копать? буду очень благодарен.

UPD: Это была проверка на существование уменьшенной копии картинки, шло по условию что ее нет. А дальше просто не могла обрезатся уменьшенная копия. Ответ оказался крайне прост - просто не хватало оперативной памяти для обработки большого изображения.

Comment: Путь к файлу у вас вероятно неверный передается в функцию. Возможно там картинки-то и нет из-за большого размера ;)

Comment: @Visman, в первую очередь проверил, возникает проблема только при больших картинках... все пути правильные и фаил по факту существует на сервере...

Comment: а сохранение файла происходит в коде непосредственно перед этим? может быть, для больших файлов имеет место ситуация, что файл еще не успел записаться на диск а вы к нему обращаетесь? Не уверен в реальности подобного, но для выяснения хотелось бы понять ваш код в части записи файла. Опять же - если запись непосредственно перед запросом filesize.

Comment: Нет. Сохранение происходит раньше нарезки. Сначала идет проверка есть ли фаил на сервере а потом уже масштабирование или обрезание. Файлы не особо большие - 5-15мб. Скорее всего проблема не в этом. Надо будет глянуть дальнейший обработчик...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Все оказалось намного проще. Дальше в обработчике вызывалась функция для маштабирования и нарезания картинки. Так как картинка имела солидный размер то и памяти на операцию надо было больше установленной, по умолчанию на процесс давалось 128м, всего лишь увеличив memory limit проблемму удалось устранить.